# How to draw regression discontinuity plot with confidence intervals using rdplot?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, causality

For example, suppose I want to draw RDD plot with confidence intervals (eg., upper and lower longdash lines) using the data below. How should I proceed?

```
x<-runif(1000,-1,1)
    y<-5+3*x+2*(x>=0)+rnorm(1000)
    rdplot(y,x)
```

**The documentation says: 
ci optional graphical option to display confidence intervals of selected level for each bin.**

Any idea how to actually use the argument `ci`?

Answer (score 2):

After reading the documentation for `rdrobust()`, I think you just supply the CI level you want for ci argument. For instance,

```
x <- runif(1000, -1, 1)
y <- 5 + 3 * x + 2 * (x>=0) + rnorm(1000)
rdplot(y, x)
rdplot(y, x, ci=95)
```

Comment: `ci` adds confidence intervals to the bins, not to the fitted line.